# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Sometimes when my application crash in logs I see this : I put my layout which I use in this adapter. In this layout i use image and I don't know what I did wrong that the my application is crashed. It doesn't happen all the time it happen sometimes and I don't know when.

```
PID: 5339                                                                     
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
   at pl.teminalmobile.Adapter.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:92)
```

This is my message_list_row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_list_row"
    android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_list_row">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_list_row">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/from"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@color/message"
            android:textSize="@dimen/timestamp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/count"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="10km"
            android:textColor="@color/message"
            android:textSize="@dimen/timestamp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_star"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_star"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:src="@drawable/confirm" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error stack?

Comment: hi plz add class file where this xml file is used.

Comment: `?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` is causing error

Comment: @ManmeetP it is a full error stack : https://paste.ofcode.org/JQbiFNhPrbf2dkQBtJe8vP

Comment: are home and confirm drawbles vector?

Comment: @FarshidABZ I use a png

Comment: Even though I could not see 'Caused by' in the logs you shared, I suspect root cause as OutOfMemoryError. Usually occurs when any application layout includes a large image file.(As you mentioned that issue is sometimes and not always)

Comment: @ManmeetP ok I try use a smaller image maybe it couse erorrs

Comment: Ok, Yes sometimes problem is background image size and resolution(just a suspect). Please let us know once you try.

Comment: @ManmeetP the bug is not in image  ?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft is causing error

Comment: So what changes did you make?

Comment: @ManmeetP I remove  ?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft  and this     android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight" and it works

Answer (score 0):

Android resize's images based on the screen size and resolution. Try to use the drawable-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi folders for your images.